# Facebook share link content

Tags: html, facebook

I have a share button on my website, I understand that the link is www.facebook.com/share.php?u=myurl. And everything works fine, but how do what it says when you click it, right now it shows my website and then "Coming Soon - Future home of something quite cool"... I did try adding &t=mytitle but nothing changed. Bellow is a screenshot. Thank you.[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with informing you that the facebook "sharer" has been deprecated and is no longer supported as it states [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/):

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported. Please use the Like button whenever
>   possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

And [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

> **What happened to the old Share button?**
>
> We deprecated the Share Button when we launched the Like button,
>   because the Like button improves clickthrough rates by allowing users
>   to connect with one click, and by allowing them to see which of their
>   friends have already connected.

You should use the [Like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) or [Send](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) buttons instead.

As for the content that is being presented in the feed, you can control that by adding [open graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) tags to the page you wish users to share, when facebook crawls your page it extracts those tags and creates the feed story.

In order to debug and see how facebook "sees" your page you can use the [Facebook Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) which will also clear the cache facebook already has for your page.